# Find maximum of row, return column name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I have four rows and six columns of random numbers between `1` and `10`. The headers atop are named `A` through `F` accordingly. I want to populate a range (A1:A6) on another sheet with the maximum number for each row. That is easy with the `MAX` function. However, in a another range (`B1:B6`), I want to put the column name to which this number belongs.

An `HLOOKUP()` won't work because a maximum value in one row is likely not unique number across the entire sheet. I am thinking a `MATCH` `INDEX` type function, but my understanding of those functions, especially in conjunction, is poor.

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
1   0   2   10  9   8
9   3   7   6   9   10
10  3   0   2   1   4
9   4   7   8   6   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your array is in Sheet1 and the columns are labelled, please try in another sheet, copied down to suit (to Row**4** since there are only four rows of numbers in your data):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:F$1,MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!A2:F2),Sheet1!A2:F2,0))
```

This will return only the first column label from a row where the maximum for that row occurs more than once.